# Error while running ASP site

Tags: asp-classic

I have set Data Source(ODBC) for running ASP Site in my local Computer selected Microsoft Access Driver.

Now I can run the whole site with out error.But If i apply leave then it will show an error.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80004005)
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an
>   updateable query. /eleave/leaveApplicationOut.asp, line 39

Updation

After giving the Write permission following error is showing
Error Type:

> jmail.Message (0x8000FFFF) The message was undeliverable. All servers
>   failed to receive the message /eleave/leaveApplicationOut.asp, line 80

Thank you very much for your support.
It is solved..

Comment: Any chance you could provide line 39 and/or some neighboring lines to give us an idea of where it is failing?

Answer (score 3):

4 possible causes are highlighted here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168

I am guessing it's #1:

> The most common reason is that the Internet Guest account (IUSR_MACHINE), which is by default part of the "Everyone" group, does not have Write permissions on the database file (.mdb). To fix this problem, use the Security tab in Explorer to adjust the properties for this file so that the Internet Guest account has the correct permissions.

Comment: Yeah, the article is worth checking out. Reason #1 is most common when you are using MS Access and you move the MDB file around here and there (from your desktop to wwwroot for example). Reason #2 is applicable to any database, you open up a read only recordset and then you try to update a record.

Answer (score 0):

First error (which seems like you solved) has to do with write permissions on the database..

The updated question ,though, seem to be completely unrelated..
You seem to be trying to send an email, right ? and it says it failed.. 
Perhaps the SMTP service is not running and so it cannot send the email ? could it be a wrong IP address defined somewhere ? wrong credentials for the email accounts ?  (read http://host.cdesystems.com/faq/jmail_faq.asp for possible problem)

give some code about the configuration you do to the jmail ..